# Solving ODE G(ax+by)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx} = (x+y+2)^2$

$let z= x+y+2$

$\frac{dz}{dx} = 1+ \frac{dy}{dx}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{dz}{dx} -1$

substitute back in:

$z^2+1 = \frac{dz}{dx}$

$\int \frac{dz}{z^2+1} = \int dx$

$arctan(z)=x+c$

Did I do something wrong? Because I cant solve for y when replacing z because it is inside of arctan.

Comment: Well. Then you have $z=\tan(x+c)$  or $y = \tan(x+c)-x-2$.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
$$ y[x] = (-2 - i) - x + \frac{1}{-i/2 + A e^{2 i x}} $$
where A is complex constant